# express-validator throwing error with valid field

Tags: express-validator

Did my best to follow the docs [here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/#basic-guide), but I can't get this to work.

**`server.js`**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/', index);
```

**`index.js`**

```
const router = express.Router()
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check')

router.post('/register', [
  check('name').exists()
  ], function(req, res) {
  const validationErrors = validationResult(req)
  if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log("validationErrors.array()\n", validationErrors.array())
  }
})
```

To test this, I am entering a valid `name` in the client, and it shows up just fine in `req.body`.  Might be worth noting that `req.body` has the following structure:

```
{ userRegistrationForm:
   { name: 'John Doe',
     email: 'john@example.com',
     password: '',
     gender: '',
     birthMonth: 'Month',
     birthDate: 'Day',
     birthYear: 'Year' } }
```

The docs mention `check('username').isEmail(),`, but I don't know where `'username'` is coming from, unless the `check()` method is looking at `req.body` by default.

No matter what I do (meaning I enter a valid name), I keep getting the same validation error:

```
[ { location: 'body',
    param: 'name',
    value: undefined,
    msg: 'Invalid value' } ]
```

**How do I correctly use the `check()` method?**

**Update**:

I think I figured it out.  I modified my client to pass `req.body.name` to the server (as opposed to `req.body.userRegistrationForm.name`), and `check('name')` seems to catch the error when I omit a name.  Still, I'd like to get feedback on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

express-validator maintainer here.

In order to select fields that are nested within other objects, you specify its path using dot notation*:

```
check('userRegistrationForm.name')
```

<sub>* I acknowledge that if you're asking, we may need better docs to cover this! PRs welcome.</sub>

Comment: That's exactly what I had to do to make it work, though I ended up just removing the `userRegistrationForm` object in the client so that I can just use `req.body.name`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add something that helped me here: Make sure to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, or the validation always fails